# How can I load this data separated by tabs in python?

Tags: python, jupyter

I have about 500 lines of data stored in the following way:

```
USGS    11456000    2000-06-01  11.0    A

USGS    11456000    2000-06-02  10.0    A

USGS    11456000    2000-06-03  9.60    A

USGS    11456000    2000-06-04  9.30    A
```

All I want is the stuff in columns 3 and 4 (date and measurement), but I am unsure how to call to these specific columns.

This is what I have tried:

```py
     filename = 'STH.txt'
     f = open(filename, 'r')


     date = []
     discharge = []


     for line in f:
          date.append(line.split('\t')[2])
          discharge.append(line.split('\t')[3])
    f.close()

    time = np.array(date)
    discharge = np.arra(discharge)

    print(discharge)
```

and I end up with an empty pair of brackets.

Comment: consider the csv module.  I think you can set tabs as the delimiter

Comment: I was going to say the same thing. Instead of having to split on the text twice you can just read it in, append it, and then select the columns you want

Comment: Since you are working in `jupyter`, can't you simply load a line or two, and experiment?  Instead of trying to do all 500 lines in one script, try it interactively.  Try different `split` values (or even the default whitespace).  Does it give you a list of strings?  A long enough list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the easiest way to read might be through pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('STH.txt',sep='\t',header=None,usecols=[2,3])
date = data[2].values
discharge = data[3].values
```

Comment: @BAKKAB, can you please accept the solution if it works for you?

Comment: yes sorry I am still new to this site and figuring out how to work it

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas library

```
import pandas as pd
dataFrame = pd.read_csv("./demo1.txt", sep="\t")
dataFrame.columns =['name','num', 'date', 'measurement'] #here you 
                                                          # can name 
                                                      #the column header
print(dataFrame['date'])
print(dataFrame['measurement'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = 'STH.txt'
 f = open(filename, 'r')


 date = []
 discharge = []


 for line in f:
      date.append(line.split()[2])
      discharge.append(line.split()[3])
f.close()

time = np.array(date)
discharge = np.arra(discharge)

print(discharge)
```

I suggest you that using .split() instead of split('\t')